# I want to extract the MAC address of the following python-wifi 0.6.1 code

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code tries to extract the MAC address of all nearby APs and then saves them in a matrix, i dont know what is wrong. it uses the library python-wifi 0.6.1. Here is the code and error:

```
    `
    import errno
    import sys
    import types
    import pythonwifi.flags
    from pythonwifi.iwlibs import Wireless, WirelessInfo, Iwrange, getNICnames, getWNICnames

    i=0
    ArregloMAC=[20][30]
    wifi= Wireless('wlan0')
    results = wifi.scan()
    (num_channels, frequencies) = wifi.getChannelInfo()
    print "%-8.16s  Scan completed :" % (wifi.ifname, )
    for ap in results:
        index = 1
        ArregloMAC[i][index-1]= str("%d-%s" % (_, ap.bssid))
        index = index+1
    print ArregloMAC`
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. you should put a little more of your stackstrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
ArregloMAC=[20][30]
```

will give you an index out of range straight off. What it says is, create a list of one element, `[20]`, then take the 31st element of that list, and assign it to `ArregloMAC`. Since the list has only one element you will inevitably get an error.

It looks like you are trying to declare a 2-dimensional array. That is not how Python lists work.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, i thought matrixes the old way could be created like that as well... upvote!